# How to find a directory with given depth from current directory?

Tags: find-file, directory, find-dired

Is it possible from within Emacs to find directories with a given depth from the current directory from within Emacs and receive their respective location in form of a list?
I want it to work cross platform...

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to use `find` for that:

```el
(let ((dirname (expand-file-name "~/"))
      (depth 3))
  (split-string
   (shell-command-to-string
    (format "find %s -mindepth %d -maxdepth %d -type d -print0 2>/dev/null"
            (shell-quote-argument dirname) depth depth))
   "\0" :omit-nulls))
```

n.b. `-mindepth`, `-maxdepth`, and `print0` are not POSIX options, so YMMV regarding portability.

Comment: I know but find would not work across different platforms.

Comment: @sidhartharya You didn't mention the requirement that the code should work across platforms in your question. Therefore, this answer is equally valid as the others. (That's why I up-voted it.) Furthermore, the gnu-`find` tool is available for several platforms. E.g., on [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows) by [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

Comment: Yes gnu find is available across platforms but I want to do it , in a way, so the user doesn't have to explicitely install something specifically for that.. And also if i had to issue a shell command why would i ask it here. But thank's i will make the edit

Answer (score 1):

The [elgrep-search](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep/) command has options `:mindepth` and `:maxdepth`. Elgrep is available via [package-install](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html) from the [melpa package archive](https://melpa.org/#/elgrep) (instructions how to add `melpa` to `package-archives` can be found [on the melpa "Getting Started" page](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started)).

You can use `elgrep` as follows to get a list of matching file names of a specific depth. In the example I search in my HOME-directory (`~/`) for files matching `\.el\'` without in-file matches (that's the `nil`) with minimal and maximal recursion depth 2.

```el
(require 'elgrep)
(mapcar 'car (elgrep-search "~/" "\\.el\\'" nil :recursive t :mindepth 2 :maxdepth 2))
```

Elgrep actually returns filematches. That are conses of the file name and a list of in-file matches. In our case the list of in-file matches is empty since we passed `nil` for the in-file regexp.
Because of that structure you need the `(mapcar 'car ...)`. See the documentation of the `elgrep-search` command for further details.

Note, that `mindepth` and `maxdepth` are also available via the gui-version `elgrep-menu`. There you can let elgrep search asynchronously. That way it does not block your Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Library `find-dired+.el` can help with this. `C-h f find-dired`:

> **`find-dired`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el).
>
> `(find-dired DIR ARGS &optional DEPTH-LIMITS EXCLUDED-PATHS)`
>
> Run `find` and put its output in a buffer in Dired Mode.
>
> Then run `find-dired-hook` and `dired-after-readin-hook`.
>
> The `find’ command run (after changing into`DIR`) is essentially this,
>   where`LS-SWITCHES`is`(car find-ls-option)`:
>
> ```
>  find . \( ARGS \) LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> Optional args:
>
> - `DEPTH-LIMITS`:   Minimum and maximum depths: `(MIN-DEPTH MAX-DEPTH)`.
> - `EXCLUDED-PATHS`: Strings matching paths to be excluded.
>                   Uses `find` switch `-path`.
>
> When both optional args are non-`nil`, the `find` command run is this:
>
> ```
> find . -mindepth MIN-DEPTH -maxdepth MAX-DEPTH
>      \( -path EXCLUDE1 -o -path EXCLUDE2 ... \)
>      -prune -o \( ARGS \) LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> where `EXCLUDE1`, `EXCLUDE2`... are the `EXCLUDED-PATHS`, but shell-quoted.

Same thing for the related commands: `find-name-dired`, `find-grep-dired`, and `find-time-dired` - they all take arg `DEPTH-LIMITS`.

---

*To reply to @Tobias's comment:* Yes, `find-dired+.el` (which extends standard library `find-dired.el`) depends on a UNIX or GNU/Linux `find` command.  On MS Windows you can use Cygwin or any other porting of the command to Windows.

Comment: As I understand the code [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) uses the external `find` program. Therefore, the same comments as for [Phils answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45521/2370) apply. Disclaimer: I had only a short glance on the code. It may be that you have some fallback there that uses emacs-internals when gnu-`find` is not available. I didn't check for that. Please correct me if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ls` command of the built-in `eshell` for listing the files with some predefined depth.

You have to specify the depth by the right number of concatenated file name generator expressions `*/`.

Example:

```el
(split-string
 (substring-no-properties
  (eshell-command-result "ls /usr/share/emacs/26.1/*/*/*/*/*/*(.)")
  )
 "\n" t)
```

The appended modifier `(.)` says that the generator only expands regular file paths.

Note that the backend [`eshell-do-ls`](https://github.com/emk/eshell/blob/c8dbfc915dc9ba7ca5f2e6ca879e3ea64dfbc660/em-ls.el#L326) command is a pure Emacs Lisp implementation of the `ls` command.
Yet in this case the actual work is not done by `ls` but by `eshell-glob`.

If you also want to list directories you should add the `-d` switch to the `ls` command. Otherwise the files contained in the directories would also be listed:

```el
(split-string
 (substring-no-properties
  (eshell-command-result "ls -d /usr/share/emacs/26.1/*/*/*/*/*/*")
  )
 "\n" t)
```

If you actually don't want any special features of `ls` you can also use pure `eshell-extended-glob`:

```el
(eshell-extended-glob "/usr/share/emacs/26.1/*/*/*/*/*/*")
```

If you want to list all files with some **minimal depths** you can expand with the two-star form `**`, e.g.,

```el
(eshell-extended-glob "/usr/share/emacs/26.1/*/*/*/**/*")
```

Comment: That's a great idea . Thank you so much.